# Minimal Model - Francesco- Null vector

Tags: field-theory, conformal-field-theory

I am reading chapter 7 on Minimal Model in the Yellow book by Francesco et al. I am currently studying conditions under which the families of conformal fields [$\phi_{r,s}$] can be made finite. So, upon the condition that $\frac{\alpha_{+}}{\alpha_{-}}$ is rational, we get the equation 7.67 of text
\begin{equation}
h_{r, s} + rs = h_{p'+r, \ p-s} = h_{p'-r, \ p+s}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
h_{r, s} + (p'-r)(p-s) = h_{r, \ 2p-s} = h_{2p'-r, \ s}
\end{equation}
They then claim that this means the null vector at level rs in the Verma Module $V_{r,s}$ is itself the highest weight of a degenerate Verma module, since it fits in the Kac formula. I am not able to understand how it fits into Kac formula. Moreover, doesn't every null vector, $|\chi \rangle $, forms a submodule, $V_\chi$, in which  $| \chi \rangle$  is the highest weight state, as discussed in the first paragraph of Section 7.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a weight fits in the Kac formula, that means it is equal to $h_{r^\prime, s^\prime}$ for some $(r^\prime, s^\prime)$. What the yellow book shows is that $h_{r,s} + rs$ is precisely such a weight because we can take $(r^\prime, s^\prime) = (p^\prime + r, p -s)$ or $(p^\prime - r, p +s)$.

You are right that every null vector $\left | \chi \right >$ of a Verma module forms its own submodule $V_\chi$. However, *a priori* it didn't have to be the case that $V_\chi$ was *also* degenerate. We could've started with a degenerate Verma module, found one null descendant $\chi$ and then seen that all descendants of $\chi$ had norms which were finite multiples of $\left < \chi | \chi \right >$. The fact that this submodule fits in the Kac formula is a non-trivial fact which tells us that there will be an infinite cascade of null states.

Comment: I approve of this answer! P. Di Francesco

Comment: Phillipe is my house for dinner, so I let hime answer!

Comment: What are the chances of that? Thanks for weighing in!

Comment: Really appreciate the answers !